# Generating XML and json from xsd , json- schema python

Tags: python

Is there any pythonic way to generate fake data from data schema (xsd,json-schema)? I didn't see any module which can do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[GenerateDS](https://pythonhosted.org/generateDS/) library might be a good point to start with. It has XSD to JSON object conversion as well.

Comment: Can it generate XML sample out of xsd, are the any code snippets that demonstrating the usage? I don't want the client tool, but integrate it in my code